# Should we use lifetime extension of a temporary in C++17 and later?

Tags: c++, c++17

Since in C++17 it's guaranteed that the temporary created by an expression is stored in a variable assigned to:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    Test()                  { std::cout << "Test()"                 << std::endl;   }
    Test(const Test &rhs)   { std::cout << "Test(const Test &rhs)"  << std::endl;   }
    Test(Test &&rhs)        { std::cout << "Test(Test &&rhs)"       << std::endl;   }

    Test &operator=(Test &&rhs)         { std::cout << "Test &operator=(Test &&rhs)"        << std::endl; return *this; }
    Test &operator=(const Test &rhs)    { std::cout << "Test &operator=(const Test &rhs)"   << std::endl; return *this; }

    ~Test() { std::cout << "~Test()" << std::endl; }
};

Test fun()
{
    return Test{};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto t = fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Test()
~Test()
```

Deleting the assignment operators and the copy and move constructors yields the same result.

Do we still need to extend the lifetime of the temporary ('const auto &t = fun()') for any kind of optimization?

EDIT:

```
Test &operator=(const Test &&rhs)   { std::cout << "Test &operator=(const Test &rhs)"   << std::endl; return *this; }
```

Is now:

```
Test &operator=(const Test &rhs)   { std::cout << "Test &operator=(const Test &rhs)"   << std::endl; return *this; }
```

EDIT: 
Question clarified.

EDIT:
Removed the 'language-lawyer' tag. This is a genuine question that affects much of my codebase. People normally use lifetime-extension of temporaries for performance reasons. But writing 'const auto &p = ...' is longer than just write 'auto p = ...', which is cleaner and expresses more the desire of the programmer.

Comment: I don't see where you're extending the lifetime of anything in that code.

Comment: @NicolBolas You don't because I'm not.

Comment: `Test &operator=(const Test &&rhs)` should not be `const` rvalue reference parameter.  Should be `(const Test &rhs)` lvalue reference.

Comment: @chila: "*You don't because I'm not.*" Then, what are you asking about? How can you ask about whether lifetime extension is needed if there's no temporary whose lifetime is being extended?

Comment: @NicolBolas They are asking that since copy elision of prvalues is guaranteed, is there a reason they would still need to capture the return value by reference and extend it's lifetime, instead of capturing by value.

Comment: _Since in C++17 it's guaranteed that the temporary created by an expression_ Where is a temporary here???

Comment: @Eljay Ups. Typo. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas 'auto p = fun()' seems to replace 'const auto &p = fun()' in C++17 and it's actually superior because you can std::move it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer 'const auto &p = fun()' would create a temporary which lifetime would be extended by 'p'. Pre C++17, if you did 'auto p = fun()', in-place construction was not guaranteed so you compiler could create a temporary and then call the assignment operator, without violating the standard.

Comment: @chila You mean "and then call the copy/move-constructor"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Everything I've written is perfectly understandable, if you know C++.

Comment: "equaled to" - you mean _assigned_ to. "Equal" is an adjective you test for, not a verb you perform. It's a good idea to keep assignment `operator=` and equality `bool operator==` very distinct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would still like this to work:

```
auto const& t = fun();
```

And for that to work relies upon extending the lifetime of the temporary `fun()` returns to match the lifetime of `t`. Otherwise, the `Test` temporary would be destroyed at end of the expression and I'd immediately have a dangling reference.

You need some way to say "give me whatever" that avoids work if the "whatever" gives you an lvalue. I don't want to do `auto t = fun();` where `fun()` returns a `T const&`, that's an unnecessary copy. `auto const&` (or `auto&&`) avoids the copy in this case, and with lifetime extension works with the prvalue case as well.

Comment: Agreed!  Pre-C++17 code that depends on `auto const& t = fun();` needs to still work as expected with C++17, and well into the foreseeable future.  (The lifetime extension of a temporary not being transitive is a limitation, but a well-known one.  Not sure if the OP's question has this in mind.)

Comment: But C++17 guarantees no copies for 'auto t = fun()'.

Comment: Instead of extending the lifetime of the temporary, no temporaries are created, and the address of the variable to be assigned is passed to the function, to be directly set (assigned, RVO, etc).

Comment: @chila • C++ tries very, very hard to be backwards compatible.  Removing lifetime extension of a temporary from the standard would break a lot of code.

Comment: @Eljay I'm not asking that. I'm asking if coders should still use it instead of direct assignment to a variable. I don't know if there's a situation where 'const auto &p = fun()' should be used from C++17 onwards.

Comment: @chila • thank you for clarifying. For code being written for C++17 (or later), I would prefer and use the pattern you've suggested.

Comment: @Eljay It seems so. The variables also have the advantage to be std::move-able.

Comment: @chila It certainly does not "guarantee no copies" if `fun()` returns a `T&`.

Comment: @Eljay I've modified the question for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @Barry You're correct. I normally use 'auto &p = fun()' for those cases. But... using 'const auto &p = ' removes the need to remember whether the function returns a value or a reference... point for 'const auto &p'.